# How can I use IsPressed property in ControlTemplate of Thumb?

Tags: wpf

I wanna to rewrite the ControlTemplate of the Thumb.

Here is the code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="123" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Border Name="B"></Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="B" Value="#575757"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="B" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, VS 2019 RC1 reports an error:
[image]

It is so strange that the IsMouseOver is all right but the IsPressed reports the error.

I found the official template of Microsoft as below:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/thumb-styles-and-templates

But the official template now is using the VisualState but not trigger.
I wanna that how can I use the IsPressed property by using the Triggers.
Maybe you will ask me why do not use the VisualState? I wrote several custom controls in the project, I don't want something using the VisualState and something using the Trigger, that's so muddledness. I just want all are Triggers.

Thank you.

Comment: Thumb doesn't have an IsPressed property?

Comment: But as the official template of Microsoft said, there is a press property in the visual state, I think there is a  press property in trigger also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thumb` does not have `IsPressed` property according to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb?view=netframework-4.7.2)

You can use other properties such as [IsDragging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb.isdragging?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_Primitives_Thumb_IsDragging)

> Gets whether the Thumb control has logical focus and mouse capture and the left mouse button is pressed.